# Keep an activity/activities alive while the app is open in the background

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, background-service, data-persistence

Hey guys I'm brand new to this site, I know people get put down a lot for asking duplicated questions so I hope this isn't one of them.

As well as this site, I am new to android programming and have **created a simple app for calculating a price based on time.**

this app has 3 activities that i use to switch layouts
1. `FirstActivity` - shows title page and button to launch second activity
2. `SecondActivity` - starts a timer and calculates price based on seconds.
3. `LastActivity` - shows the end  results of time and price and allows the user to share this with other apps (email, sms)

Everything is working fine, however when the phone orientates the current activity is killed and restarted I've fixed this by forcing the layout to portrait - I've now run into this problem again when i move the app to the background

**SO THE ACTUAL QUESTION: I need my `SecondActivity` to keep time, and my `LastActivity` to keep the saved info even if the user switches apps.** I'm not talking about when the app is closed im talking about when the app switcher or home button are activated and my app is still open in the background.

thank you in advance!

Comment: y u want to do it at all..bcoz app is suppose to be removed from list if it remains in background for long time or when memory is low

Comment: not clear ...elaborate more

Comment: 2023: check out https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services "foreground service". It'll save you so much time as we developers just want to run code when the app isn't shown but no one mentions this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the end I just needed more information on how to implement the Data Save features that everyone suggested and that android has, I found the answer I needed here: [How to make an android app return to the last open activity when relaunched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441203/how-to-make-an-android-app-return-to-the-last-open-activity-when-relaunched)

**To solve the problem**
I needed to add:
|1|  a new `Activity`  |2|  `<action>` and `<category>` tags to the activity  |3|  `SharedPreference` setters in each activity I needed to keep.

1. Per @JosefPfleger's intructions I made a new blank activity named `RestorePrevActivity` and in the android manifest set it as `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` and `DEFAULT` I also removed all the intent filters in my first activity as they were defaulted there after creating the app for the first time.

   ```
    <activity
      android:name=".FirstActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name=".SecondActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:launchMode="standard">
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name=".LastActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_last"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:launchMode="standard">
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name=".RestorePrevActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   ```
2. After setting the action and category of my new activity i needed to add code to the activity. this was added to `onCreate()` of `RecoverPrevActivity`

`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Class<?> activityClass;

    try {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
        activityClass = Class.forName(
                prefs.getString("lastActivity", FareActivity.class.getName()));
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        activityClass = FareActivity.class;
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(this, activityClass));
}
```

where `FirstActivity` Would be replaced with the default activity you would run if no previous activity could be found.

3. finally I went through my activities and added an `OnPause()` that saved the activity name.

I added the following code segment to all my other activities and now its working flawlessly.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("thisActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Where `thisActivity` is changed to the name of the current activity.

**Result**
I was able to launch my app, start the timer and then press the home button or app switcher to safely switch apps or even lock the screen and upon return it successfully brought back my timer that was running uninterrupted! I put it to another test and ran clash of clans, a memory heavy game and I also watched Youtube videos for about 30 with my app running in the background and came back to my app to see the time was correct and ran perfectly while I was gone.

Answer (score 1):

When your app goes on background on stop method call and you can do what you want

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        // you can store you values here!
        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity_Name.this);
        getPrefs.edit().putBoolean("running", true).commit();
        getPrefs.edit().putString("name", "save this string").commit();

        // to retrieve values anywhere in your application
        boolean a = getPrefs.getBoolean("running", true);
        String str = getPrefs.getString("name", "");
    }
```

you can have detailed look on this

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you need a `service` if the timer has something to do. But if you only need to store the information, you could store them in a file or a database every time `onPause()` is called. Recalculate the prize by the gone time in `onResume()`

`onPause()` makes sense, because it's called then your app loses focus.

`onResume()` because it's called every time your app gets the focus again.

For further information look at the activity life cycle.

[image: activity life cycle]

source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: android documentation explains that onResume() is only called if the user returns to the app from onPause(); in the case of a complete app switch, home button, or back button the onPause() will instead run onStop() and destroy my activity.

Comment: @StephenMiller look at the picture I added in my edit it will call `onStop()` but `onPause()` will also be called.

Comment: hey ive tried the saveinstance state and preference methods with no luck, they get deleted onstop or onpause so my next course of action is studying up on the read/write ability like you suggested. that way i can just save the start time and calculated the time elapsed from that, Thanks! (ps would upvote everyone if i could but im still only lvl 1 or whatever that means)

Answer (score 0):

You must differentiate between the app and the activity.
The app stays in the background for a longer time than the activity. If you rotate the device, the activity gets restored.

You need to store and restore the state of the activity as described in the android lifecycle manual:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

If you need to do timed background tasks take a look at the TimerTask:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html