# Start last open Activity in android after pressing App icon

Tags: android, task, manifest, launcher

I have the following constellation:

Press App Icon open **Activity A**, which checks which activity should open next (Registration or Main **Activity B**). **A** is marked as Main Launcher in the xml. Now I go to **B**. Then I have a user action and come to **Activity C**. Now I press home. If I chose  the app again from background task selector i come back to **C**. But when I instead press the app icon again,I will start again with **A**. Is it possible to handle it in manifest that in this case **C** should open again or do I have to care it by myself (e.g. via SharedPreferences?)

Comment: it should be done by android itself i am surprise why you are facing these problem

Comment: read this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441203/how-to-make-an-android-app-return-to-the-last-open-activity-when-relaunched

Comment: I have to add, that A B and C are already singleTask. As i only allow one instance.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be controlled in the `manifest` via `android:launchMode`.

See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode
and more explanation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

for your scenario, you'd want to keep C and route new intents to the existing instance of it, so this might work:

```
<activity
   android:name="A"
   ...
   android:launchMode="singleTask" />
<activity
   android:name="B"
   ...
   android:launchMode="singleTask" />
<activity
   android:name="C"
   ...
   android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Comment: Wont work. after pressing the app icon and app gets back from background, A will be started. A B and C are already "singleTask"

Comment: try "singleInstance" then, pressing the app icon probably started a new task altogether instead of using the existing task

Comment: ah, another option - try removing launchMode from all 3 activities, Android may bring A to the top of the task when relaunched because of the custom launchModes, "standard" (or no launchMode at all) shouldn't behave like that