# Not opening the activity on Top

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an **`Activity A`**. On a button click, I have started the **`Activity B`** like this

```
{               
    startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
}
```

When I am in the **`Activity B`**, I have pressed the home button. If I re-launch the app it is navigating to A, instead of B. Could some one guide me how is it possible to navigate to B?

Comment: May be your app is being killed and relaunching the launcher activity. Please share full code.

Comment: Post Activity A code and Activity B code

Comment: It is not killed. When re-opening, it is invoking the onResume(). onCreate() is not called.

Comment: look into it this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441745/4549435

Comment: Probably a reason that app is being killed by Os. Anyway  post your manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in the manifest file, which was causing the issue. Removing this line resolved my issue.