# How to open particular activity using shortcut?

Tags: java, android, android-shortcut

I am trying to open particular activity using shortcut but always run application.

When application is running in background and click on shortcut icon -> particular activity is open.

If application is killed from background then how to open particular activity using shortcut.

*** Below method use for create shortcut**

```
private void createShortcutOfApp() {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        YourTargetActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "App shortcut name");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
    R.mipmap.logo_of_your_app_shortcut));

    addIntent
        .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so   don't duplicate
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

**permission in manifest**

```
uses-permission  android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
```

**define in manifest**

```
android:name=".YourTargetActivity"
android:exported="true"
```

I am tired to solve this problem, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Follw below link to know how to open particular activity on relaunch application.
**It works for me.**

[How to make an android app return to the last open activity when relaunched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441203/how-to-make-an-android-app-return-to-the-last-open-activity-when-relaunched)

Comment: i don't want to open last opened activity, i want to open particular activity which is define in createShortcutOfApp() look at method.